# Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net, ajax, sharepoint

I am working on sharepoint 2010. I have created a simple visual web part which contain one text box and I have added calendarextender to it. I have added `ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll` as reference. But when I deploy to sharepoint site then it gives me following error.

"Parser Error" Message:

> Could not load file or assembly  'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot  find the file specified.

Source Error:

> Line 3: <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"> Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

Source File:

> /_CONTROLTEMPLATES/VWP_Ajax/VisualWebPart1/VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx Line: 9

Any ideas where Im going wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is the AjaxControlToolkit.dll in the bin directory after you deploy the site?

The assembly (AjaxControlToolkit.dll) needs to be deployed to the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) or put in the \BIN folder of the SharePoint site's folder.

Answer (score 2):

This definitely worked for me with SharePoint 2010 ...

**Error Code:**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"  TagPrefix="ajaxControlToolkit"%>
```

**Working Code:**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.60501.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"  TagPrefix="ajaxControlToolkit"%>
```

Comment: Working Code: <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.60501.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"  TagPrefix="ajaxControlToolkit"%>

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to explicitly set the full assembly name in your register command.  I found that I had to update my code to include this to get it to work properly:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30930.28736, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

For third-party controls like this, it's worth being as specific as possible to avoid any errors if versions change.

Answer (score 0):

Even you tried above and it wont work, Just add another Page/MasterPage and add `ToolKitScriptManager` on it.It will create Bin Folder at required path. If still there is Error check the Register Assembly line on newly added page/MasterPage and copy that Register Assembly line to other pages wherever your error is.